# xcode swift 5 ios 14 example project video stream to server like janus jitsi mediasoup webrtc RTMP, HSL, etc

Tags: swift, xcode, video-streaming, webrtc, rtmp

Is there an example Xcode project compatible with Xcode 11 or 12 and IOS 14 that sends video streaming to a web server in linux or other.

The basic : open the camera, button to start streaming, the code to stream and output video+audio...

is there any project that is open source and connects to Janus, Jitsi, MediaSoup or any other libraries ?

Is there an example with `AVfoundation` ??

Or example via HSL, RTMP aor any other protocol ?

Any recent stuff ? when I search in stackoverflow or google I find stuff that dates like 7 or 9 years ago with dead links or inactive old project :(

••• EDIT •••
I found a few... anyone tested those ?

UNPAUSE https://github.com/unpause-live/SwiftVideo

GAMERA https://github.com/NilStack/Gamera

YTLiveStream https://github.com/SKrotkih/YTLiveStreaming

VIDEOCAST : https://github.com/cats-oss/VideoCast-Swift

MUXINC : https://github.com/muxinc/examples

Answer (score 0):

I found a GOOD ONE : openvidu.
https://openvidu.io/demos#0

I even was able to modify the record script to restream ;)
[ffmpeg x11grab to streamable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837454/ffmpeg-x11grab-to-streamable-format)